# CustomListAdapater SharedPreferences Not Saving State when closing App

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I want the notes I set in the CustomListAdapter to be there until the user removes them. Whether the user closes the app, phone restarts or anything else the notes they have added need to remain there until removed. I have tried to do this by getting the Sharepreferences in my tab and setting them in the CustomListAdapter but they don't save:

I added a counter so I could retrieve the value at a later stage to remove and call the method addnote in the customerListAdapter to set the SharedPreferences.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

    final EditText notes = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    final int cross = R.drawable.cross;
    notesofrules = new ArrayList<String>(); //initial data list

    pref =   getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), notesofrules, cross);

    listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //set the adapter once, only manipulate the data within

    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                String newNote = notes.getText().toString();
                adapter.addNote(newNote, counter, editor); //add new note to the adapter list
                counter++;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //very important to notify adapter and refresh the listview
                notes.setText("");

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Activity context;
        private ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
        private ImageView image;
        private int imageCross; //make this a list if you have multiple images and add similar to notes list

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> notes, int imageCross) {
            super(context, R.layout.item,notes);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context=context;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.imageCross = imageCross;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);

            final TextView ruleNotesSet = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            image.setImageResource(imageCross);
            image.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    notes.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            ruleNotesSet.setText(notes.get(position));
            return rowView;
        }

        public void addNote(String data, int position, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
            editor.putString(Integer.toString(position), data);
            editor.commit();
            notes.add(data);
        }
}
```

Can't see where I have gone wrong, how can I set them and then remove them within the onClick in the customListAdapter?

Edit:

I have added this within Tab:

```
adapter.getNotes(pref);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is the getNotes method in the CustomListAdapter:

```
public void getNotes(SharedPreferences pref)
        {
            for(String note : notes) {
                pref.getString(note, note);
            }
        }
```

Still not setting the state back once closed .

I also edited the addNote method:

```
    editor.putString(data, data);
```

Comment: I might have missed it because there are lots of  code in your question but I can't see where you are retrieving your sharedpreference value.

Comment: Yep just realised that, i'm creating a getNotes in the customerAdapter and passing the prefs through it. Will update if it doesn't work, just trying it.

Comment: @Kunu I've added a new method to retrieve the Sharepreferences but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this within the Tab class. Setting the sharedpreferences as the user clicks the button. Then checking if it is null when creating the view again. Then getting all the preferences and storing it into a Map and passing it to the adapter within onCreate. Whoop. Hope it helps someone one day.

```
String notesInStorage = pref.getString(Integer.toString(counter), newNote);

  if(notesInStorage != null)
        {
            Map<String,?> keys = pref.getAll();

            for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){

                notesofrules.add(entry.getValue().toString());
                adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), notesofrules, cross);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

u add this code to save the data u want 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("position", position);
 editor.apply();
and to get 
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
Int position = prefs.getInt("positon", null);
and use it